# operator '&' is not defined for string insert into and type 'byte()' in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

[image]

Im trying to send a data using TCP but the error says that **operator '&' is not defined for string insert into and type 'byte()'.**

```
Dim ms1 As New MemoryStream
Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream
Dim data1 As Byte()
Dim data2 As Byte()

PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms1, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
PictureBox2.Image.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

data1 = ms1.ToArray()
data2 = ms2.ToArray()

Dim sendbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Passenger_idTextBox.Text & "," & Last_nameTextBox.Text & "," & First_nameTextBox.Text & "," & Middle_nameTextBox.Text & "," & StreetTextBox.Text & "," & BarangayTextBox.Text & "," & CityTextBox.Text & "," & Contact_celfoneTextBox.Text & "," & Contact_landlineTextBox.Text & "," & Contact_emailTextBox.Text & "," & AgeTextBox.Text & "," & ComboBox1.ValueMember & "," & ProfessionTextBox.Text & "," & data1 & "," & data2)
TCPClientz.Client.Send(sendbytes)
```

Comment: data1 and data2 are byte arrays. There's no automatically "right" way of converting those to strings which is what you're trying to do by concatenating them onto the end of that string. There are quite a few issues here that you don't seem to have considered - such as the fact that TCP deals with an unending stream of bytes in both directions - not *messages*, and the fact that any one of your text controls *may* currently contain a comma.

Comment: Hello sir. I dont have any idea on this. What should I do.? TY

Comment: You can't just magically expect the binary data from an `Image` to become a `String` and fit into comma-delimited text. You have a very dodgy protocol if you have something at the other end waiting for that particular data. What EXACTLY is the server expecting?

Answer (score 0):

data1 and data2 are byte arrays, not strings. 
You cannot use & to concatenate arrays of bytes.
Here's a way how you can concatenate byte arrays:

```
Dim x As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String("test")
Dim y As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String("test")
Dim z As Byte()
Dim barr As New Collections.Generic.List(Of Byte)(x)
barr.AddRange(y)
z = barr.ToArray
```